# CXF client integration with external soap service with proxy support from esb wso2

Tags: spring-boot, soap, wso2, cxf, esb

in my application i need to integrate with the external soap web service. In my application I have implemented a connection to this external service using cxf apache ver. 3.3.3. The service returns correct data when I connect to it directly. However, I need to connect using a data bus wso2 EI.
I have created a proxy service on the wso2 and I want to connect to an external service using this proxy service.
When in my application I change the url of the service to the address of the proxy on the bus, communication is not improved. I get an error like below:

```
 javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response message did not contain proper response data. Expected: 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:195) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na] caused by: org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl$IllegalEmptyResponseException: Response message did not contain proper response data. Expected: 
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.processResult(ClientImpl.java:666) ~[cxf-core-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:539) ~[cxf-core-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441) ~[cxf-core-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356) ~[cxf-core-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314) ~[cxf-core-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
... 96 common frames omitted
```

What's more, I tested the proxy on the bus using SoapUi and it returns the correct answer. What is the problem and how to solve it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the direct invocation from CXF client to backend service work?

Comment: yes, if I don't use esb, it works, and if the address proxies, it doesn't